# Get week from unix timestamp retrieved from database

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have a MySQL database. In a couple of tables, the information that gets stored needs to be retrievable by week. So, I want to be able to do a `SELECT FROM *database* WHERE week = *week*`. The problem that I have is that the week part is stored as a unix timestamp (to allow for more versatilty like getting the date and time, just time, etc...).

**So the question:** How can I retrieve this record `WHERE date = *date*` when the stored `date` is a unix timestamp and `date` I'm matching it against is not?

If my question is too confusing and something needs to be rephrased or said in a clearer manner please comment and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a built-in `WEEK()` method for handling dates: [MySQL WEEK() Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

Unfortunately however, MySQL's WEEK() method only supports `DATE` datatypes rather than a `UNIX TIMESTAMP`. Therefore, we must first convert the timestamp to a date so we can then pass that date to the WEEK() method:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  WEEK(
    DATE_FORMAT(
      FROM_UNIXTIME('my_unix_timestamp_col'),
      '%e %b %Y'
    )
  ) = 51
```

If you have a column which is the `DATE` data-type, the query can be simplified (and can also use indexes):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE WEEK(my_date_col) = 51
```

Comment: To make it more simple, how could I create the date in a more usable format?

Comment: I dug into the week method a little more and did discover that it does not appear to take a unix timestamp as I originally thought. As such, I've modified the code accordingly. And you are correct, replace 51 with your PHP code to specify the current week.

Comment: To make it more simple, how could I use the date in a more usable format so that your origional code would work? The time() part doesn't matter, just that it is as easy as possible.

Comment: Instead of storing UNIX_TIMESTAMPs, I'd recommend creating a column with the `DATE` data-type.

Comment: This technique will retrieve rows matching week 51 in every year. You may also want to match the year.